# How can I check if an object exists in a List by specialized comparing way?

Tags: java, list, compare

For example I have a List as `List<MyClass>`.

`List.contains()` will use `Object.equals()` for comparing, so I have to implement the method `MyClass.equals()` with correct semantic, but I can't modify it.

Is there an API that can use the specialized comparing method/class for checking except for loop & check by myself?

The list is not sorted list so I can't use `Collections.binarySearch()`.

Comment: Why can't you modify it? `@Override`?

Comment: @Kuma Managed by another team, modifying it will cost much time...

Comment: Then make a function to manually loop the `List` to find a match.

Comment: @user2310289 `Object.equals()` just comparing the address of objects, Its result isn't correct for this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a custom `contains()` method for a single instance of a `List`, during instantiation such as this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            // your own implementation
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

The contract for the method contains() is:

> **java.util.Collection**
>
> Returns true if this collection contains the specified element. More
> formally, returns true if and only if this collection contains at
> least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

Hence I think it is no good idea to override the method, violating the contract. Due to the fact that your *List* isn't sorted, finding a matching element is *O(n)*, where *n* is the number of elements contained in the *List*.

Iterating over each element as suggested by *songyuanyao* in the answer above should not hurt and is straight forward.

Another solution would be to use [com.google.common.collect.Collections2.filter()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html) which takes a Collection and a predicate and returns another collection containing only elements matching the predicate.